# change dataformat and pass it to the csv dataframes pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

So I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv(rawdata_trg, sep='\t', index_col=False, header=0, parse_dates=[0])
```

from a csv-file:

```
Time    A
2020-03-04 15:46:42 10
```

I want to change the date format *from 2020-03-04 15:46:42 to 04.03.2020 15:46:42*.
It works fine with:

```
a = data_frame.iloc[0]['Time'].strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(a)
```

Output:

```
04.03.2020 15:46:42
```

but when I then print my df, I can't see any difference.
How can I "save" the new date format to the csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the new date format to the entire 'Time' column, you can use the apply method on the column and pass the strftime function:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Then you can save the updated dataframe to the csv file:

```
df.to_csv(rawdata_trg, sep='\t', index=False)
```